# How to make EL relational operators to work on Tomcat 8/JSTL 1.2

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, tomcat8

I'm having a strange behavior since our upgrade from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 8.0.32.

Relational operators (<, >, <=, >=) are not working with variables defined with c:set

```
public class ServiceConstants {
  public static final Integer MY_CONST = 15;
}
```

Below is my code (updated):

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="a" value="<%=ServiceConstants.MY_CONST%>"/>
<c:set var="b" value="${127}" />
<html>
<body>
<br/>a: ${a}
<br/>b: ${b}
<br/>Using variables {b > a}: ${b > a}
<br/>Using variables {b gt a}: ${b gt a}
<br/>Hardcoded values {127 > 15}: ${127 > 15}
</body>
</html>
```

And below is what is rendered

```
a: 15 
b: 127 
Using variables {b > a}: false 
Using variables {b gt a}: false 
Hardcoded values {127 > 15}: true
```

When comparing a and b set by c:set it is returning the wrong answer.

Below is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

  <absolute-ordering />

  <distributable/>

  <display-name>App name</display-name>

  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
      <taglib-uri>http://xyzo.org/app</taglib-uri>
      <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/app.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

I tried several solutions posted, changing to Tomcat 8.0.37 (latest), change my web.xml file header and such.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT BELOW:

I've found out that the numbers are being interpreted as strings by EL.
If I force cohersion it works but seems cumbersome.

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="a" value="<%=ServiceConstants.MY_CONST%>"/>
<c:set var="b" value="${127}" />
<html>
<body>
<br/>a: ${a}
<br/>b: ${b}
<br/>Using variables {b > a}: ${b > a}
<br/>Using variables {b gt a}: ${b gt a}
<br/>Hardcoded values {127 > 15}: ${127 > 15}
<br/>...
<br/>Forcing cohersion
<br/>Using variables {b > (0 + a)}: ${b > (0 + a)}
</body>
</html>
```

It results:

```
a: 15 
b: 127 
Using variables {b > a}: false 
Using variables {b gt a}: false 
Hardcoded values {127 > 15}: true 
...
Forcing cohersion 
Using variables {b > (0 + a)}: true
```

Any tips on how to make EL to do the 'right thing' still would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried gt (greater than) instead of >? Like b gt a? See also http://www.javatips.net/blog/jstl-less-than-greater-than

Comment: Yes, I tried and it didn't work either.. also updated the code in the question so other people can see it as well.. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

If you use expressions when setting the variables it's less cumbersome:

```
<c:set var="a" value="${15}"/>
<c:set var="b" value="${127}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately that wouldn't work as I'm getting Integer values out of a Java class using scriptlet as the edit question above.